# how to deploy OSGI bundle to CQ5 system console through command prompt or through maven command

Tags: console, maven-3, aem, osgi-bundle

I have a project requirement to deploy the OSGI bundle(packaged as JAR) in CQ5 system console from command prompt or maven command.

**what I looking for -** 
Is there any way ,I can deploy my available OSGI bundle that is packaged as Jar to the CQ5 system console directly using command prompt or maven command.

**what I tried -**
I found a way that this can be achieved through - "cURL", below is the command for this :

```
curl -u admin:admin -F action=install -F bundlestartlevel=20 -F bundlefile=@"C:\osgi-work\demo-file-search-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles
```

but as per the requirement,I can't restrict user to first install **"cURL"** then run the command.

Is there any workaround to install my OSGI bundle directly to CQ5 console manager.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Maven to build your bundle, you could include the [Maven Sling Plugin](http://sling.apache.org/site/sling.html).

Assuming you've the correct properties included in your POM (or settings.xml), you could then simply call `mvn sling:install` to install the bundle into Felix.

You could also use multiple profiles, e.g.:

```
mvn sling:install -P development
mvn sling:install -P qa
```

Assuming that each profile would hold a URL for that environment & the credentials needed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the maven-sling-plugin you can also just copy bundles and content packages in a folder named "`install`" in CQ's JCR repository, provided that folder is under `/apps` and not more than 4 or 5 levels deep (I don't remember the exact number).

So for example mounting the JCR repository (`http://localhost:4502` by default) via WebDav, creating a folder named `/apps/yourstuff/install` and copying your bundles in there will cause the Apache Sling OSGi installer to install them as if that had happened via the OSGi console. The installer only considers the latest version of a bundle, in case multiple copies are supplied in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `mvn -P autoInstallBundle`? You will need to add the autoInstallBundle profile in your pom file:

```
       <profile>
        <id>autoInstallBundle</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>my-project</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>                                
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>          `
```

Look here for more information: [http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/aem-how-tos/development/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html#Bundle Development Tasks](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/aem-how-tos/development/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html#Bundle%20Development%20Tasks)

Comment: If you want to improve your maven workflow even further, take a look on the parent pom of either the Apache Sling project or of the Adobe CQ5/AEM product. ( https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/parent/pom.xml )